# Spring data using through ThreadPoolTaskExecutor

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I would want to know the behavior of spring data when used in tasks running by an executor.

1. I'm wondering what will happen in case i run spring data persistent operations from tasks planned by an ThreadPoolTaskExecutor that has maxPoolSize set to 1000 meanwhile the database max-connection is set 100 ?
2. What will happen again if i use a semaphore of 100 limit slots in my task to protected each specific persistent step ?

I just want to use persistent operation with spring data from tasks scheduled from a executor and before going that way i want to know the relation between Spring data and thread pool.

Comment: what's the point of having 1000 threads trying to use 100 db connections?

Comment: We process a huge geojson data. For that we have to split the processing in plenty sub process that can run in parallel. In the same time at the end of each process some data need to be saved. And the database max connection is limited

Comment: If you have 1000 threads, do you have a 1000+ cores? :) Obviously not. So your threads are just going to be task switching and getting swapped in and out all the time. If your max db connections is 100, you'll never be able open more then 100 db connections at a time. Is this a personal project, or are you running in AWS? Can the chunks be independent of each other? My INITIAL hunch (without knowing more) would be something like the main process to just split the json data into chunks and send it out on Kinesis where you would have up to 100 lambdas process and save it out.

Comment: Have you actually benchmarked it capping the threads to less then the number of cores? And then see if increasing beyond the number of cores makes it faster or slower?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.